# All items in a Kotlin array always contain the last item

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, android-videoview

I'm trying to populate an array with files in my raw folder. I then pick a random slot in that array and use it to play that file.

But when I do this, every slot seems to contain whatever was the final video in the array. I'm not sure what the cause of this is...

```
    var videos = Array(5){R.raw.c0; R.raw.c1; R.raw.c2; R.raw.c3; R.raw.c4};

    videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + videos[Random.nextInt(0, 4)])
    videoView.requestFocus()
    videoView.start()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're initializing the array incorrectly.

The `{...}` block after the `Array(5)` is actually a lambda that takes an integer and returns the content for that index in the array. The semicolons (rather than commas) mean that each of `R.raw.c0`, `R.raw.c1`, etc. is just a statement that doesn't do anything. Since `R.raw.c4` is the last statement in that block, it sets all five indexes to that value.

You probably meant:

```kotlin
val videos = intArrayOf(R.raw.c0, R.raw.c1, R.raw.c2, R.raw.c3, R.raw.c4)
```

Note the replacement of semicolons with commas.  I also switched the `var` to a `val`, as you don't appear to be changing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing one of the following to correctly **create** your array.

```
var videos = intArrayOf(R.raw.c0, R.raw.c1, R.raw.c2, R.raw.c3, R.raw.c4)
```

or

```
var videos = arrayOf(R.raw.c0, R.raw.c1, R.raw.c2, R.raw.c3, R.raw.c4)
```

Please try it, this should solve your problem.

Comment: Why do you think this is better than Ryan M's older answer?

Comment: It shows two ways of creating array correctly in Kotlin for solving the problem.